# Populate textbox From Select Options using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application in PHP where one needs to add multiple raw materials. These raw materials are added using select box of which the first select box is the default added in HTML and the other rows are added using JavaScript. Now, I need to add get more data such as raw material unit_price from the database after selecting an option from the select box then fill text box along that row with data from the database. The first row has no problem and its okay, but all the rows where the select options are coming from JavaScript the textboxes are not being filled with data.

I tried the following code but only the default select box is working, the rest of the select boxes populated with JavaScript, no textbox is being filled

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Fetch options for select dropdown
            $.ajax({
                url: 'fetch_options.php',
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    populateSelectOptions(JSON.parse(response)); // Populate select options
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });

            //`Function to populate select options
            function populateSelectOptions(options) {
                options.forEach(function(option) {
                    $('#raw_material').append(`<option value="${option.code}">${option.material_name}</option>`);
                });
            }

            // Event listener for select change
            $('#raw_material').change(function() {
                var selectedOption = $(this).val();
                if (selectedOption !== '') {
                    // Fetch data associated with the selected option
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'fetch_data.php',
                        method: 'GET',
                        data: { id: selectedOption },
                        success: function(response) {
                            populateFormFields(JSON.parse(response)); // Populate form fields
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            // Function to populate form fields based on selected option
            function populateFormFields(data) {
                $('#total_quantity').val(data.total_quantity);
                $('#total_cost_price').val(data.total_cost_price);
                $('#unit_price').val(data.unit_price);
                // Populate other form fields as needed
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Here is The code to add new rows

```
<script>
                  function addRow() {
                      var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
                      var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);

                      var rawOptions = document.getElementsByName('raw_material[]')[0].innerHTML;
                      var quantityOptions = document.getElementsByName('quantity[]')[0].innerHTML;
                      var TotalCostOptions = document.getElementsByName('total_cost_price[]')[0].innerHTML;
                      var TotalQuantityOptions = document.getElementsByName('total_quantity[]')[0].innerHTML;
                      var UnitPriceOptions = document.getElementsByName('unit_price[]')[0].innerHTML;
                      

                      newRow.innerHTML = `
                          <td style="border:none;">
                              <select class="form-control" id="raw_material" onchange="populateTextbox(this)" name="raw_material[]" required>
                                  ${rawOptions}
                              </select>
                          </td>
                          <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control" placeholder = "Batch Quantity" style="width:150px" type="number" name="quantity[]" required/></td>
                          <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control" style="width:120px" type="text" id="total_cost_price" name="total_cost_price[]" required/></td>
                          <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control" style="width:120px" type="text" id="total_quantity" name="total_quantity[]" required/></td>
                          <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control" style="width:120px" type="text" id="unit_price" name="unit_price[]" required/></td>
                          
                      `;
                  }

                  function removeRow() {
                    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
                      if (table.rows.length > 2) {
                          table.deleteRow(-1);
                      }
                  }
              </script>
```

Anyone to assist how I can fill the rest of textboxes where the rows are being populated with JavaScript

Comment: Looks like you are using same ids in HTML. Remember, there should only be one id per element in HTML page

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but where exactly if you could point out where it shows the Id have been duplicated?

Comment: Just open page source when it is loaded and search for `raw_material`, `total_quantity`, `total_cost_price`, `unit_price`. How many times do you see these ids? If they are more than once that's where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks once again but all Ids' are okay
my only challenge is that the new rows added with JavaScript are not able to populate textboxes

Comment: You are adding change event listener on select box with id `raw_material`. This will only work for first select box on the page no matter how many new select boxes you add later on.

Comment: Can you share the code which adds new rows? You must be using the same raw_material id to every new select element

Comment: I'll attach the code to the original question
Let me know if any other code is required

Comment: As i suspected, you indeed are using duplicate ids which won't work. Consider converting id's to classes instead. Add event listeners on classes and populate the text boxes only in the row of select element with the help of this reference.

Comment: could you please share an example with a code?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments.
The code was not working due to same ids present on the html page.
Well, there are many possible ways to fix the things.
But here is the one in which i have added event listeners on the classes. There are no duplicate ids on the page.

This is just mimal working version to show you how you can get it working. No a full fix, You can always refine it to your needs.

Hope that helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Fetch options for select dropdown
  /* $.ajax({
      url: 'fetch_options.php',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
          populateSelectOptions(JSON.parse(response)); // Populate select options
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
  }); */
  // Let's assume this is your ajax call returned data which populate the select option          
  const opts = [{
      code: "1",
      material_name: "Material 1"
    },
    {
      code: "2",
      material_name: "Material 2"
    },
  ];
  populateSelectOptions(opts);

  //`Function to populate select options
  function populateSelectOptions(options) {
    options.forEach(function(option) {
      $('#raw_material').append(`<option value="${option.code}">${option.material_name}</option>`);
    });
  }

  $('#addRow').click(function() {
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);

    var rawOptions = document.getElementById('raw_material').innerHTML;

    newRow.innerHTML = `
        <td style="border:none;">
        <select class="form-control raw_material" name="raw_material[]" required>
          ${rawOptions}
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control quantity" placeholder="Batch Quantity" style="width:150px" type="number" name="quantity[]" required /></td>
      <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control total_cost_price" style="width:120px" type="text" name="total_cost_price[]" required /></td>
      <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control total_quantity" style="width:120px" type="text" name="total_quantity[]" required /></td>
      <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control unit_price" style="width:120px" type="text" name="unit_price[]" required /></td>`;
  })

  // Event listener for select change
  $(document).on('change', '.raw_material', function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    if (selectedOption !== '') {
      // Fetch data associated with the selected option
      /* $.ajax({
          url: 'fetch_data.php',
          method: 'GET',
          data: { id: selectedOption },
          success: function(response) {
              populateFormFields(JSON.parse(response)); // Populate form fields
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.error(error);
          }
      }); */
      // Let's assume this is your ajax call returned data
      const data = {
        total_quantity: 3,
        total_cost_price: 23,
        unit_price: 24
      };
      populateFormFields(data, $(this));
    }
  });

  // Function to populate form fields based on selected option
  function populateFormFields(data, elem) {
    const target = elem.closest('tr');
    target.find('.total_quantity').val(data.total_quantity);
    target.find('.total_cost_price').val(data.total_cost_price);
    target.find('.unit_price').val(data.unit_price);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
<table id="tblMaterial">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:none;">
      <select class="form-control raw_material" id="raw_material" name="raw_material[]" required>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control quantity" placeholder="Batch Quantity" style="width:150px" id="quantity" type="number" name="quantity[]" required /></td>
    <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control total_cost_price" style="width:120px" type="text" id="total_cost_price" name="total_cost_price[]" required /></td>
    <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control total_quantity" style="width:120px" type="text" id="total_quantity" name="total_quantity[]" required /></td>
    <td style="border:none;"><input class="form-control unit_price" style="width:120px" type="text" id="unit_price" name="unit_price[]" required /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```